# What is wrong with this Threading example?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Process dies when trying to put InputStream to Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304950/process-dies-when-trying-to-put-inputstream-to-amazon-s3)

- I have an `API` that has a method `OutputStream getOutputStream(String id)`
- This `API` has two concrete implementation - `FileService` and `S3Service`
- I have a documentManager that does the following

> ```
> public void putDocument(@Nonnull final Document document) throws IllegalArgumentException, PersistenceException {
>         final OutputStream stream = persistenceService.getOutputStream(document.getUniqueId());
>         try {
>             jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(document, stream);
>         } catch (final JAXBException e) {
>             LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
>             throw new PersistenceException("Failed to marshall document " + document.getUniqueId() + ": " + e.getMessage(), e);
>         } finally {
>             try {
>                 stream.close();
>             } catch (IOException e) {
>                 throw new PersistenceException("Failed to close output stream for " + document.getUniqueId());
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

where `DocumentManager` writes to `outputStream` returned by persistenceService

- This implementation works well with `FileService`
- With `S3Service`, we have to convert this `OutputStream` to `InputStream` to comply with `Amazon S3 API`([here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream,%20com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata%29))
- so I did following in `S3Service.getOutputStream`

  ```
  public OutputStream getOutputStream(@Nonnull final String uniqueId) throws PersistenceException {
       final PipedOutputStream outputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
       final PipedInputStream inputStream;
       try {
           inputStream = new PipedInputStream(outputStream);
           new Thread(
                   new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                           objectMetadata.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
                           PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new     PutObjectRequest("haritdev.sunrun", "sample.file.key",
                                       inputStream, objectMetadata);
                           PutObjectResult result =      amazonS3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
                           LOGGER.info("result - " + result.toString());
                           try {
                               inputStream.close();
                           } catch (IOException e) {

                           }
                       }
                   }
           ).start();
       } catch (AmazonS3Exception e) {
           throw new PersistenceException("could not generate output stream for " + uniqueId, e);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           throw new PersistenceException("could not generate input stream for S3 for " + uniqueId, e);
       }
        try {
           return new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
           throw new PersistenceException("Failed to get output stream for " + uniqueId + ": " + e.getMessage(), e);
       }
   }
  ```

When I debug this, I see that the process dies after a while and document is not written, is this implementation incorrect?

Comment: you are not cathcing exceptions `AmazonS3Exception, AmazonServiceException` in `run()` method. What if these exceptions are thrown?

Comment: adding exception did not help either

Comment: well, actually that was not solution but that was flaw in your program. I do not know answer.